# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=2 when using a Singleton

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview

I have a Singleton to manage some variables I need in various places in my app. This is the singleton, called General:

```
#import "General.h"

static General *sharedMyManager = nil;

@implementation General

@synthesize user;
@synthesize lon;
@synthesize lat;
@synthesize car;
@synthesize firstmess;
@synthesize firstfrom;
@synthesize numcels;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    if (sharedMyManager == nil) {
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
});

return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    user = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"vacio"];
    numcels=0;
}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
// Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
}

@end
```

I use it in a TableView that present in screen messages of a part of my app that is a chat.
I mean, everytime the app receives or send a message, i add 1 to the var "numcels", and that is the value that numberOfRowsInSection method returns.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];
return *(general.numcels); //It freezes here
}
```

The problem is, when i run the program, it freezes at the commented line, saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2. I guess that the problema may be with the singleton, but don't know where it is exactly.

Any help? Thank you in advance.

-------EDIT--------

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"Hemos entrado en cellForRowAtIndexPath");
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
if(!cell){
UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}
General *general = [General sharedManager];
NSString *text=general.firstmess;//it crashes now here
NSString *remite=general.firstfrom;
[[cell textLabel]setText:remite];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:text];

return cell;
}
```

And the General.h, by request:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface General : NSObject {
NSString *user;
double lat;
double lon;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *user;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double lat;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double lon;
@property (assign, nonatomic) Boolean car;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *firstmess;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *firstfrom;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int numcels;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

Comment: why are you doing *(general.numcels); ..? i mean what's the idea behind star?

Comment: If i dont do that, it shows a warning "incompatible pointer to integer conversion..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After solving the first issue (thanks to the kind help of Ankit), it crashed in the line I have commented below the EDIT. I simply changed

```
@property (nonatomc, assign) NSString *firstmess;
```

to

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *firstmess;
```

And it doesn't crash anymore.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It should be like the following:

`return general.numcels;`

`numcels` is an integer and you cannot apply the `*` operator to it.